# Minimizing a project costs through dynamic programming

Tags: combinatorics, optimization, problem-solving, nonlinear-optimization, dynamic-programming

I have a project and I want to minimize the costs. I am responsible for the inspection of 1000 miles of sewer grid in Canada. My goal is to provide time high quality inspection reports. I tried to define the problem using optimization but I haven't used for a year. I want to know what would be the optimised number of people I should hire.

The people I have to pay are robots drivers and inspectors.

- I have a $\$90000$ budget, two months on site and two weeks off site before.
- robots drivers take 6 pictures of every pole under different point of views and upload them on my cloud. The drivers upload their pics once a week.
- A well trained driver can inspect 15miles of sewer grid per day. Training lasts for one day, you can train two pilots in parallel.
- A photo inspector performs a quality check of the pictures on the Sterblue cloud. Sterblue asks the drone pilots to reinspect any poles not passing the quality checks. You can assume 10% of the poles have to be re-inspected.
- My AI on the cloud detects the defects. The customer expects 95% accuracy.
- The inspector performs a quality check of the detections found by the AI. They cost $300 a day and can handle 30miles/day for image quality review, 30miles/day to review the work of the AI.
- I have a free operations team that generates the inspection reports. 0,5 day is needed to prepare a report for 100 miles of grid.

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{aligned}
\min \ &800 \overbrace{x_1.y_1}^{\text{robot pilots x days}} &+ 300  \overbrace{x_2.y_2}^{\text{inspectors x days}}\\
&800 x_1.y_1 &+ 300 x_2.y_2&\le $90000\\
&y_1&+y_2 &\le 2 months\\
&15 x_1.y_1&&\ge 1000 miles+10\%x_1.y_1 \\
&15 y_1 &&= 30 y_2 \\
\forall i, x_i
\end{aligned}
\end{cases}
$$

Where $x_1$ is the number of robots drivers, $x_2$ the number of inspectors, $y_1$ the time spent by robot drivers, $y_2$ the time spent by inspectors.

I know that inspection can't start before reports, and that I haven't found a way to write the 95% accuracy constraints.

- Can you help me improve the problem so I take into account every constraints ?
- What should $x_1$ and $x_2$, the number of people I should hire, be ?

I know I should do a Gantt diagram as well but I don't know yet where the major steps and dependencies are.

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you might try asking this question on the new [or.se] Stack. I'd suggest also making it a bit clearer what you are asking. Is it just the 95% constraint?

Comment: Another goal might be to get rid of the nonlinear terms (e.g., $x_1\cdot x_2$) as much as possible.

Comment: Finally, I wouldn't assume that this is a dynamic programming problem. Your partial formulation is not a DP. It's possible that DP is the right approach, but a more straightforward (non)linear optimization approach might be the right way to go.

Comment: @LarrySnyder610 Yes but also what should $x_1$ and $x_2$ values (the human resources) should be. Thanks for the link. I4m going to ask there if I don't get any answer here. Please let me know what's unlcear so I can update it. If there is anything I can add, let me know :)

Comment: Surely the sewer authority (or whoever it is that you work for) can afford to hire a mathematical consultant, instead of relying on random strangers on the internet?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sure ! It's me, the intern ^^ The question is real but the way I proposed (using optimization, dynamic or non-linear programming) comes from my own initiative :)